# Does this change in the paypal´s api affect Drupal6´s Ubercart-Paypal Integration?

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-6, ubercart

I´ve just got this message today. Does this change in the paypal´s api affect Drupal´s 6 Ubercart-Paypal Integration?

> In keeping with industry standards set by the Certification
>   Authority/Browser (CA/B) Forum, PayPal will discontinue supporting
>   1024-bit key length certificates and will migrate to 2048-bit
>   certificates before the end of 2013.
>
> We have completed the installation of 2048-bit certificates for all
>   API endpoints in our PayPal Sandbox and Payflow Pilot environments,
>   and we will be doing the same for our production environments starting
>   on August 6, 2013.
>
> We strongly encourage merchants to thoroughly test any existing
>   integration(s) in the PayPal Sandbox and/or Payflow Pilot environments
>   to ensure this migration will not cause any unforeseen issues.
>
> Please have the team or person responsible for your integration refer
>   to the following:
>
> If you need to import the new PayPal Sandbox and/or Payflow Pilot
>   server certificates to your application or system truststore, you can
>   download production and Sandbox certificates from
>   https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/952.
>
> If you don't typically import the server certificates to your
>   truststore, you can proceed with testing with no other action
>   required.
>
> If you have any questions, please contact PayPal Merchant Technical
>   Services by filing a ticket; refer to PP-LIVE-3503. You may also visit
>   our Live Site Status blog.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> PayPal

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine unless you're using Payflow. Most people on Ubercart are using Website Payments Pro/Standard.

There's no reason to update anything for a normal Ubercart install to keep working. See

https://drupal.org/node/2030733

Where maintainers TR and Longwave weigh in.